# Is it possible to enqueue an instance method, as opposed to a function, using Python-RQ?

Tags: python, redis, task-queue, python-rq, django-rq

The examples provided in the [Python-RQ](https://python-rq.org/docs) documentation consistently show functions being enqueued, using `queue.enqueue()`. For example:

`job = q.enqueue(count_words_at_url, 'http://nvie.com')`

Is it possible to enqueue a method of a particular object instance? And if so, is this considered reasonable practise?

For example:

```
member = Member.objects.get(id=142)
job = q.enqueue(member.send_email())
```

If the answer to either of the above questions is no, what is the reccommended pattern to approach this situation?

One possiblity I had considered was to create a helper function, that is independent of the Member model. For example:

```
def send_member_email_bg_task(member_id):
    Member.objects.get(id=member_id).send_email()
```

and enqueue it as follows:

```
job = q.enqueue(send_member_email_bg_task, member.id)
```

I would be grateful for suggestions on the best way to approach this.
Thanks

Comment: The bound method is `member.send_email`, not `member.send_email()`, just as the function is `count_words_at_url`, not `count_words_at_url()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enqueue any queueable object. In this case, that object is the bound method `member.send_mail`, not the object that results from the call `member.send_email()`.

```
member = Member.objects.get(id=142)
job = q.enqueue(member.send_email)
```

The bound method produced by `member.send_email` wraps both `member` and `type(member).send_email`, and when called calls the wrapped function with `member` as its first argument.

Comment: In your example, when the worker picks up and executes the work, will it call send_email() on the same instance of member? ie where member.id=142 ?

Comment: Yes; `member.send_email.__self__ is member`, so when when the bound method is finally called, it will do so using `member`.